# Add datepicker to laravel register form

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I tried to add the date picker to Laravel 5.4 registration form, but I have no idea how to do that. It's necessary for my app to have this option as required field in register from.

Currently, I have only simple text input field, but I need to use the date picker field.

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('birthday') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="birthday" class="col-md-4 control-label"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> Birthday</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="birthday" type="text" class="form-control" name="birthday" value="{{ old('birthday') }}" required autofocus>
        @if ($errors->has('birthday'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('birthday') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I have this column in my user's schema `$table->integer('birthday');` I'm not sure if `integer` is correct for this column or not will be appropriate for your suggestions.

any idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [date picker library](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

And initialize that date picker by this,

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#birthday" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

You should use `varchar(25)` in database to store this field.

Comment: @robertnicjoo have you included the "jQueryUI" library? It will not work without it.

Comment: i did but not worked so i used laravel default date schema table which will get eg. 10/03/2017

Comment: @robertnicjoo Okay. But it should work. I have used this in my almost 5 sites. And it is working like a charm. Meanwhile, you can also check this bootstrap library, https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_textbox_datepicker_id').datepicker({ 
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",

        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
         }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $('#form').formValidation('revalidateField', 'your_textbox_datepicker_id');
            });
```